# error TS2356 says Number type variable must be an arithmetic operand of type 'number'

Tags: javascript, typescript, setinterval

this is what my class definition looks like:

```
timeLeft: Number;

constructor() { 
    this.timeLeft = 60;
  }

  start() {
    console.log(typeof(this.timeLeft)); // prints out 'number'

    setInterval(() => {

      this.timeLeft--; // error TS2356 occurs here
      console.log(this.timeLeft);

    }, 1000);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
```

Console:

> error TS2356: An arithmetic operand must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.

Comment: I'm pretty terrible with Typescript but a cursory glance at the documentation indicates that `timeLeft` should be of type `number`, not `Number`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by Phil in the comment section, it is better to use 'number' instead of 'Number'. 'Number' refers to non-primitive boxed object that is almost never used appropriately in JavaScript code.
Refer: [Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html)